# Servlet Multi-Threading, the place of the worker thread created

Tags: multithreading, tomcat, servlets

Servlet creates one new thread to process the request per request， so where is the
thread created? Is it created by the servlet container like tomcat?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Servlet creates one new thread to process the request

No. The servlet doesn't create any thread. The container (Tomcat, for example) is the one creating threads. And it doesn't create a new thread per request. It has a pool of available threads, gets one from the pool to handle a request, handles it, and then puts the thread back to the pool of available threads.

Comment: Got it! The thread-pool is StandardService, right? In which Class the Runnable is created in tomcat?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by that.

Comment: Does a request represent one runnable? I see the code in the org.apache.catalina.Executor  `void execute(Runnable command, long timeout, TimeUnit unit);`